# how do i assign a different backgroundcolor to all the items in a group in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have **three groups** in my `NavigationDrawer`, two of which have to stay **white** and the other one has to become **gray**.
I have seen many people say that it would be better to use a `ListView` to do this but I wonder if its possible with a menu?

Comment: Thanks for accepting. you can upvote if it is useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the background color to your navigationView like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/adcl_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/app_white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_layout"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/app_secondary_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/app_secondary_text"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And if you want to change Single item background color then use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/my_ripple"
        app:itemIconTint="#2196f3"
        app:itemTextColor="#009688"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```